# What is the relationship between spin network spacetime and tensor network (entanglement) spacetime?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, gravity, quantum-entanglement, quantum-gravity

In 1971, Sir Roger Penrose, suggested a [combinatorial construction of spacetime](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/penrose/Penrose-AngularMomentum.pdf) using the angular momentum of particles. This work led to and introduced the idea of spin networks which are representations of particle interactions where vertices represent events in spacetime and edges represent the worldlines of resultant particles. In such a way one can use these diagrams to illustrate the information held in a system.

In 2010, Mark Van Raamsdonk, wrote an essay outlining how [spacetime can be built from quantum entanglement](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.3035.pdf) building off of the ideas of [Malcadena and Susskind](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.0533.pdf) which have now come to be known as the ER = EPR conjecture. Brian Swingle provided a [mathematical framework](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.1317.pdf) to present these ideas in the form of Tensor Networks, typically used in Many-Body physics, where AdS/CFT has been found to be ubiquitous.

What is so different between these two approaches? Or what, if any, are the relationships between the two bodies of work?

Can one reduce the work of Van Raamsdonk to that of Penrose?